# " Notice of Suspected Hacking" by google webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

i received a  messages with the above notice "Notice of Suspected Hacking on my website. I'm not sure what happen here, however, I noticed there were some pages listed and they are not apart of my website??

Has anyone received the same message before? If so, what did you do to solve the issue?
and what i do for the next?

Comment: you might get better answers on a dedicated webmaster site such as http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be some malware virus introduced that pages in your site. Remove all pages and rescan them and upload again. May be it will solve your problem.Also check if there are any suspicious javascripts included your pages.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Google detected malicious links in your site... (generally spam).

Generally a quick scan at http://sitecheck.sucuri.net finds the issue.